# Probability that automated process is 95% accurate given n sucesses

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have trained a robot to flip an (unbiased) coin and get heads every time. Each flip is with a new coin (more on that shortly). How many successes does the robot need before I can be confident (say 95%) that the robot is trained to do the task?

How will this change if we know a given proportion (say 10%) of coins are biased, making success less likely by chance (say pHEAD=0.3)?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, after $n$ successful flips (assumed independent), the (exact) lower $(1-\alpha)$-confidence bound for the probability your robot lands heads is $\alpha^{1/n}$. So after 10 flips the 95% confidence bound is $(.05)^{1/10} \approx 74\%$, after 20 flips it's $(.05)^{1/20}\approx 86\%$, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for you input Dedekind Cuts. I did consider a similar approach. However, I am not sure that this i) accounts for the prior expectation that the robot will always succeed ii) does it address the "probability that the robot will always throw a head (or 95% of the time) _given_ that it has had _n_ successes". It seems like we have only addressed the "probability of _n_ successes" (with the assumption that p=0.5) so far. But I may be wrong.